# LocationMatch Regex for versioning

Tags: regex, apache, locationmatch

I've tried using the docs but I'm quite new to regex. I've had success with others but the same method is not working for what I'm actually after.

I'm trying to send users to different servers based on the version number in the URL. This this case, older versions are to be sent to the new server for a particular service.

```
<LocationMatch "/(1.0|2.0|3.0)/appname">
    ...
</LocationMatch>
```

The following is working -

```
<LocationMatch "/1/appname">
    ...
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "/2/appname">
    ...
</LocationMatch>
```

What I would love to achieve is sending all those major releases with a single tag -

```
<LocationMatch "/(1*|2*|3*)/appname">
    ...
</LocationMatch>
```

I've already referred the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch but unfortunately it doesn't cover my case with enough detail to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(1.*|2.*|3.*)/appname
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I wanted to specify a version? eg: 1.X

Comment: No luck unfortunately.

Comment: Updated my answer, and it should work how you were trying to get it to work.

Comment: I'm using it as <LocationMatch "/1.*/service/start/pool"> and attempting to access it as http://domain/1.2/service/start/pool but instead of going to the proxy path specified it just goes to /1.2/service/start/pool